# My row deletion process is working fine for a single sheet. How can it be done for all sheets of a spreadsheet having specific names?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I can delete all unprotected rows of data from a sheet using App Script. The sheet name comes from a user input of another sheet named 'Dashboard'. But now I need to delete all unprotected rows of data from all sheets of a spreadsheet having both alphabets and numbers in their names. Please note that I have two types of sheet names like CSE4115, ICT1234, MATH4101, etc. (both alphabets and number) and also Master, Dashboard, TempDataSet, etc. (only alphabets in their names). So I need to do deleting all unprotected rows of data from sheets like CSE4115, ICT1234, MATH4101 and so on. No user input is required I think.

My codes are as follows:

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Tasks')
    .addItem('Data Cleansing', 'dataCleansing')
    .addSeparator()
    .addToUi();
}

function dataCleansing(){   
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var allsheets = ss.getSheets();
  for(var s in allsheets){
    var sheet = allsheets[s];
    
    if((sheet.indexOf("0")>-1 || sheet.indexOf("1")>-1 || sheet.indexOf("2")>-1 || 
      sheet.indexOf("3")>-1 || sheet.indexOf("4")>-1 || sheet.indexOf("5")>-1 || 
      sheet.indexOf("6")>-1 || sheet.indexOf("7")>-1 || sheet.indexOf("8")>-1 || sheet.indexOf("9")>-1)){ 
  
      //For removing unprotected rows of data from a particular sheet  
      // 1. Retrieve data range.
      const dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();

      // 2. Create an object from the protected range. This is used for removing from the cleared rows.
      const protectedRanges = sheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE).map(e => {
        const r = e.getRange();
        const start = r.getRow();
        return {start: start, end: r.getNumRows() + start - 1};
      });

      // 3. Create range list for clearing rows using the object.
      let rangeList = [];
      for (let r = 2; r <= dataRange.getNumRows(); r++) {
        let bk = false;
        for (let e = 0; e < protectedRanges.length; e++) {
          if (protectedRanges[e].start == r) {
            r = protectedRanges[e].end;
            bk = true;
            break;
          }
        }
        if (!bk) rangeList.push(`A${r}:${r}`);
      }

      // 4. Delete the rows without the rows of the protected ranges.
      if (rangeList.length > 0) sheet.getRangeList(rangeList).getRanges().reverse().forEach(r => sheet.deleteRow(r.getRow()));
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested, but I think you should change this bit:

```
var allsheets = ss.getSheets();
```

to:

```
const allsheets = ss.getSheets().filter(sh => /\d/.test(sh.getName()));
```

which basically says "get all sheets which contain a number/digit (0-9) in their name)" and lets you get rid of the `IF` check below:

```
if((sheet.indexOf("0")>-1 || sheet.indexOf("1")>-1 || sheet.indexOf("2")>-1 || 
      sheet.indexOf("3")>-1 || sheet.indexOf("4")>-1 || sheet.indexOf("5")>-1 || 
      sheet.indexOf("6")>-1 || sheet.indexOf("7")>-1 || sheet.indexOf("8")>-1 || sheet.indexOf("9")>-1))
```

---

Unrelated:

- You use a `for-in` loop to iterate over `allsheets`, but since `allsheets` should be an array, it might be better to use `for-of`. In other words: `for (const sheet of allsheets) { ... }`
- Is `A${r}:${r}` valid or does it need a column reference after the `:`? Not sure, just pointing it out in case.